# Open source equivalent to Trello?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, project-management

I have registered and started to try Trello, from https://trello.com today, and it looks very nice. I can use it for my own lists, however I will perhaps not be able to share with people for projects, because Trello is available in English only.

Also, I am a long time user of FOSS software (and a contributor too, I love contributing to FOSS).

This is why I am wondering: is there an equivalent to Trello in open source somewhere? I have started to search the web, and didn't find any so far. Does someone here know about one?

Eventually, would you know about one already provided with several languages even if not FOSS?

Comment: I doubt that just ‘alternative to some non-free software’ is a good way to describe your wishes.  Judging on how Wikipedia describe that ‘Trello’, I guess, you might be interested in [taiga.io](https://taiga.io) [(FSD)](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Taiga.io) [(WP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiga.io).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: According to [this](https://trello.com/c/XFlKVtFe/1405-trello-internationalization-localization) so is Trello available in: Brazilian Portuguese, Spanish and German. (And French seems to be just around the corner.) But that might still not be the language you want it in?

Answer (score 2):

[Kanboard](http://kanboard.net) is a nice alternative but it somewhat immature.

It easy to install, it uses sqlite by default.

It has the columns as Trello. You can create projects, users, swimlanes, change locales, assign tasks. It has a nice dashboard with all of your projects.

You can move task from one column to another one.

It has nice diagrams for analyzing tasks [image: nice diagrams for analyzing tasks]

And what you are looking for a project when you can download the code and contribute it: [kanboard at Github](https://github.com/fguillot/kanboard).

The calendar feature is still somewhat immature, you cannot click on it and create tasks, it has a bug that when you move a daily task for a specific hourly one, it moves to 1969/12/31.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal CMS (open source) there is 2 alternatives:
OpenAtrium and OpenLucius, both open source too because based on Drupal. From your Trello starting point of view I would suggest the latter (OpenLucius) to explore first.