# Open source todo and logging

Tags: open-source, web-apps, project-management

We're a small team of 4 people working in technical support. We're currently using iOS Reminders app with a shared list for quickly jotting down stuff that must be done.

It gets the job done but only for stuff that must be done. Logging whatever either of us did to be able to scratch the task off as done is a real pain.

Ideally an open source web app with user login, todo and what was done functionality is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [python](http://python.org) [trac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trac/1.0.7) package, to quote:

> Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software
>   development projects. Trac uses a minimalistic approach to web-based
>   software project management. Our mission is to help developers write
>   great software while staying out of the way. Trac should impose as
>   little as possible on a team's established development process and
>   policies.
>
> It provides an interface to ​Subversion and ​Git (or other version
>   control systems), an integrated Wiki and convenient reporting
>   facilities.
>
> Trac allows wiki markup in issue descriptions and commit messages,
>   creating links and seamless references between bugs, tasks,
>   changesets, files and wiki pages. A timeline shows all current and
>   past project events in order, making the acquisition of an overview of
>   the project and tracking progress very easy. The roadmap shows the
>   road ahead, listing the upcoming milestones.

Full installation instructions are [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall).

If you take advantage of the VCS integration then you can tell which changes to the code, by whom, resolved each issue or implemented each new feature.

Trac is free, gratis and open source.

## User Interface

The main user interface is via web pages so if you have tablets or phones that can connect to the companies intranet you will be able to edit the details of tickets, check for additional open tickets near your current location, etc., via them.

## Important Note

Any such system is only as good as the data that is given to it - this needs discipline and either a willingness to share information or a set of rules to make sure that the information is shared.  Using a wiki, *(which trac provides)*, is one way of enabling the sharing of information but if nobody puts the information into it it will be useless while building the use of tickets, *(which trac also gives you)*, into your workflow and ensuring that they are filled in properly, possibly by most people only being able to mark tickets as "ready to close" and checking the details provided before actually closing the tickets.  While this requires discipline and people ***will*** moan about the additional overhead but the benefits of taking a more professional approach will be great as you will build up an institutional knowledge base, *as opposed to individuals building a personal knowledge base*, that will be more and more valuable over time.

It will also allow the generation of actual statistics that will be valuable, e.g. being able to show that you are getting 25% more incidents per month is a lot more likely to get you the funding for additional staff than simply saying "we are busier than ever".

Comment: I second that – see my answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185 "Free incident management tool for more than 50 users") and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13391/185 "Open source project management software") for some additional details.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying out [Trello](//trello.com/), as it does fulfill your list of requirements, and then some.

Here is what Trello says about it self :

> *A Trello board is a* list of lists filled with cards, used with a team or by yourself.
>
> Drag and drop cards between lists to show progress. Add as many people as you need and drag them to cards. Add and reorder lists as you need. Trello adapts to your project, team, and workflow.
>
> You’ll see everything about your project just by glancing at the board, and it all updates in real-time. There’s nothing to set up and everyone gets it instantly.

Trello has user login, and uses lists of cards to keep track of progress. Each task is a card, and can hold loads of information like task description, comments, check lists, who is assigned to task, and much more.

In addition to being a web app, it is also available on smartphones as dedicated apps.

Note that compared to trac it does not have email integration to issue tracker, wiki, connections to source control systems, but to keep track of tasks in a technical support team I would say it could be very suitable. It also provides lots of configuration options to tailor it to your needs. In other words trac and Trello battles in different leagues, so to speak.

And finally, did I mention it is free, and you don't need to install anything (besides the iOS or Android app if you'd like to).

#### Edit: Regarding the open source aspect

Trello is not open source, but I've used it both in private and corporate settings and are very satisfied with this tool. If you are determined on going opensource, a comment on [Open source equivalent to Trello?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/15056/14982) says that you might want to look at [Taiga](//taiga.io/) (still in beta), or possibly [Kanboard](//kanboard.net/). I haven't tried any of those myself.

Comment: It does not seem to be available under an open source license, or am I missing something?

Comment: @unor, Sorry about that, I just read your specifications and missed out on the "ideally open source" part. Trello is not open source, but it is a good product! ;-)

Comment: I’m not the OP ;) Good edit!

Comment: @unor, I saw that, but it is a good call, and I should have written "reread the specifications", or something in my previous comment, which I can't edit any more... :-(

Comment: If the requirement weren't open source, trello would be an obvious choice. It's great, but my boss won't allow anything we cannot host by ourself. I will definitely check out Taiga though. Seems awesome. Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest gitlab, its self hosted, open source, has a todo list (task list) and shows what has been done

https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/